# Lagging Javascript Card Game

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make a card game in javascript. I want the user to see the front of a card when clicking the button ”clicky” and then the back of the same card when clicking again. On the click after that I want it to switch to the front of the next card and so on. As it is now I reload the page with five new cards when the fifth card has been shown. Each card is an item in the variable cards and the element that changes with each click is the p tag with the id card.

My code is working but if I have more cards, about seven, it starts lagging. Is it a bad idea to have two functions that calls each other like this? Is there a better way to write this code so that I can have more cards?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id=”card”></p>
<button id="clicky">Fråga</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cards = [[”front1”, ”back1”], [”front2”, ”back2”], [”front3”, ”back3”], [”front4”, ”back4”], [”front5”, ”back5”]];

    var a = 0;
    var clicky = document.getElementById("clicky");
    clicky.addEventListener("click", function(){setFront(a)});

    var card = document.getElementById(”card”);

    function setFront (a) {
        card.textContent = cards[a][0];
        clicky.addEventListener("click", function(){setBack(a)});
    }

    function setBack (a) {
        card.textContent = cards[a][1];
        a += 1;
        if (a < 5) {
            clicky.addEventListener("click", function(){setFront(a)});
        } else {
            clicky.addEventListener("click", function() {
                window.location=url;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have `”` instead of `"`?  Don't edit code in a word processor (like MS Word).

Comment: Ok, I will remember that!

Comment: The thing that stands out to me is that you only have one `clicky` element, but in every function you're adding a new event listener to it - and *never* removing event listeners. That means eventually it's going to be calling 4 listeners, and 4 new listeners in that one click. See if you can rearrange your logic to operate off of **one** `onClickyClick` function, and add some state variables to help it decide what's going on and what it should do next.

Comment: With every addEventListener, you should have a removeEventListener.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was adding a couple of removeEventListeners right away but it still seems to be lagging. I get what is wrong now though. If I don't get it right I'll try to rearrange it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some tasks which can impact the performance of the page?
If so, you could use the "web workers", it will stop the "animation lag" while theses tasks are performed.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: No, it's just this javascript code, so I don't think that should be necessary.